# A tight positivity conjecture about sums over divisors of square-free integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, alternating-expression, squarefree-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime number and all variables, unless otherwise specified, are natural numbers.

> **Conjecture:**
> For all square-free $n \geq 2$, the following function evaluates to a *positive* integer:
> $$F(n) = -1 + \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \sum_{a^2 = 1\mod d, \ \\ 0 \leq a \lt d}\left\lfloor\frac{\frac{12}{5} p_{\text{max}}(n)-a}{d} \right\rfloor$$
> where $p_{\text{max}}(n)$ is the maximum prime divisor of $n$.
> And this conjecture is *tight* with respect to the constant $C = \frac{12}{5}$.  Any deviation to a lower value will yield a false conjecture.

**Verification Code:**

```
from sympy import *

N = 5000
epsilon =  0.00000000    # Try setting to 0.000000001

for n in range(2, N):
   if all(j == 1 for j in factorint(n).values()):  # n is square-free
      m = ((12 / 5) - epsilon)* max(primefactors(n))
      S = -1
      for d in divisors(n):
         for a in range(0, d):
            if (a ** 2 - 1) % d == 0:
               S += (-1) ** primeomega(d) * floor((m - a)/d)         
      assert S > 0
      print(m,n, S)
```

---

What is interesting is that $\{ \bar{a} \in \Bbb{Z}/d : a^2 = 1\mod d\} \leqslant (\Bbb{Z}/d)^{\times}$ is a subgroup of the units modulo $d$ and you can't change *that* either unless you adjust $C$.

Anyway, was wanting some information about sums of this type.  There's not much data on the web that I could find about strictly sums over divisors of square-free integers.  When you remove the square-free requirement, the summation goes chaotic, i.e. takes on negative or positive values.  Are there any good papers out there about this?

---

**Attempt.**  This doesn't attempt to answer the question but instead partially prove the result for when $n = q$ is a prime number.  Let $[z]_q =$ the usual (least, non-negative) residue of $z$ modulo $q$, for any $z \in \Bbb{Q}$.

$$\begin{align}
F(q) &= -1 + \sum_{d \in \{1,q\}}\mu(d) \sum_{a^2 = 1 \pmod d} \lfloor\frac{\frac{12}{5} q - a}{d} \rfloor \\
&= -1 + \frac{12}{5}q -  \lfloor\frac{\frac{12}{5} q - 1}{q} \rfloor - \lfloor\frac{\frac{12}{5} q - (q-1)}{q} \rfloor \\
&= -1 + \frac{12}{5}q - \frac{\frac{12}{5}q - 1 - [\frac{12}{5}q - 1]_q}{q} - \frac{\frac{12}{5}q - (q-1) - [\frac{12}{5}q - (q-1)]_q}{q} \\
&= -1 + \frac{12}{5} q - \frac{12}{5} +\frac{1}{q} +\frac{[\frac{12}{5}q - 1]_q}{q} -\frac{12}{5} +1 -\frac{1}{q} + \frac{[\frac{12}{5}q + 1]_q}{q} \\
&= \frac{12}{5}q - \frac{24}{5} + \frac{[\frac{12}{5} q - 1]_q}{q} + \frac{[\frac{12}{5} q + 1]_q}{q}
\end{align}$$

Now plug in $q = 2$.  We have:

$$
\frac{24}{5} - \frac{24}{5} + \text{ two numbers that can't both be zero} \gt 0
$$

since the function can only (clearly) take on integer values, we have that $F(2) \geq 1$.  By induction, for larger primes, the value is clearly also $\geq 1$.  $\blacksquare$

What remains to be proven is that it's true for $F(n)$ with $\Omega(n) \gt 1$, $n$ square-free.

Comment: What is meant by " tight with respect to a constant " ?

Comment: @mick that is explained in the post.  But basically, if you change the constant in a certain direction, then the conjecture no longer holds, by any change amount that is.  But if you keep the constant as stated, the conjecture holds.  But this is not a good formula to use if you're starting out (I saw your other post).  By Sieve of Eratosthenes, the largest number we can plugin in place of $12/5 p_n$ is $p_{n+1}^2 - 2$.  That's for $k = 1$ sep primes.  For general $k$, it's $p_{n + 1}^2 - -(k + 1)$.   The form I posted about in your answer puts in $n$ in place of $p_{n + 1}^2 - (k+1)$ ...

Comment: $n$ and so then we take the primorial of $\sqrt{n + k}$ in the summation bound.  That simply means $p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot p_3 \cdots p_{\pi\sqrt{n + k}}$.  Where $\pi$ is the prime counting function. So that is in English the product of all primes $\leq \sqrt{n + k}$.

Comment: The above post I made is just noticing that we can take $b$ much smaller than $p_{n + 1}^2 - (k + 1)$ namely down to $12/5 p_n$ at least.  Since it is definitely smaller than $p_{n + 1}^2 - (k+ 1)$, it would imply the higher $b$ version.  Reason is by construction of the formula.  When you derive it you see that it's an inclusion-exclusion set counting function.